# Adding values from textbox to 2-d array or list?

Tags: c#, arrays

i have a form where values from textbox need to be stored in an 2-d array 
the values are cloth length, quantity and cut value, which are entered into a listbox, so while displaying these values into labels while selecting from listbox, i use the array.

the problem is there any other data structure than 2-d array like list or the collection classes which can be useful. removing values from 2 d array is too much code every time.

Comment: you can use Dictionary <string, string>

Answer (score 2):

You could use one of these:

- `List<Cloth>`
- `Dictionary<string, Cloth>`

Answer (score 0):

There are no problems to remove items from array (by index I suppose):

```
array = array.ToList().RemoveAt(...).ToArray();
```

But if you plan to have many of such, then you should, as RononDex suggested, use List-based storage from start.